# C3P0 settings is ambiguous

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I work at distributed system with multiple servers working with front MySQL DB, and replicated DB in different various of queries.
Several servers use of compounds up to 1000 connections (700 - 800, 900 in hard times).

Periodically I have the problem with closed connection by MySQL and see already boring exception:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 65,179,696 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

MySQL settings of wait_timeout is default and equals 28800 (8 hours)

I use C3P0 paired with hibernate for service my connections to MySQL and have next C3P0 settings on all servers in all hibernate-custom*.xml:

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/ibaserver?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=cp1251&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">********</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">59</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
```

Can anybody answer what I'm doing wrong? Why periodically lost connection

Comment: It looks like the pool returned a connection that was not used (idle) for 18 hours. The `c3p0.timeout` and `c3p0.idle_test_period` settings should have prevented that. Can you verify these settings are actually used as configured?

Comment: Shoud I use "autoReconnect=true" in the connection.url together with c3p0.idle_test_period ? What if I leave only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Use the validation query on borrow from the pool to avoid the MySQL closed your connection exception.

**UPDATE**

The validation query you define doesn't run without some extra configs, these should suffice:
hibernate.c3p0.validate=true
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true

Comment: How can I do that?  Existing setting hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery = select 1 already doing it, isn't it?

Comment: aha, I didn't notice. I use other pools, I suspect there is some config missing so that this doesn't really run.

Comment: hibernate.c3p0.validate=true

Comment: hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true

Comment: I think this is not the solution. As official C3P0 says: 
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#testConnectionOnCheckout
   But I hardly understand what have I missed?

Comment: `c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout` should avoid all client-visible Exceptions of this sort. but your existing config should as well. it's probably worth checking that your config is what you expect (c3p0 logs its config at INFO on pool initialization, or you can use JMX). your app might be leaking Connections or otherwise holding Connections open for some reason. backstoppy things you can try include c3p0.maxConnectionAge and c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout.